# Array as first argument in Rails.cache.fetch method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am reading about the Rails cache fetch method. All the examples I read are passing a string as the first argument in the method. But, when I was reading the code from a Rails project, I saw an `array passed as the first argument in cache fetch method.`

```
  def self.get_new_sitemap(https_version = false)
    Rails.cache.fetch(['sitemap_city_block', https_version], expires_in: 5.days) do
      modified_key = 'key1'
      LocalCache.set(modified_key, Date.today)

      protocol = (https_version ? 'https' : 'http')
      url_list = get_sitemap_urls(https_version)
      content = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
        xml.urlset('xmlns' => "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
          'xmlns:xsi' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
          'xsi:schemaLocation' => "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd") {
          url_list.each { |url|
            xml.url {
              xml.loc url[:loc]
              xml.lastmod url[:lastmod] if url[:lastmod].present?
            }
          }
        }
      end.to_xml
    end
  end
```

I am unable to understand the logic behind passing an array. In some cases, the array of size 3 is passed.  
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the rails source code reveals the (private) method [`Rails.cache.expanded_key`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe76a95b0d252a2d7c25e69498b720c96b243ea2/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L649-L667).

This method does a few things. In particular, it calls: `key.to_param`. **This converts the array into a string**.

So in other words, you're allowed to call `Rails.cache.fetch` with an array (or a hash!), but under the hood the cache key will still be a string.